# Excel find all where col b = x

Tags: excel, indexing, match, offset

I have had this problem a little while and any offset etc is a bit messy and leaves gaps in what I'm attempting.

*Sheet 1*

```
+-------+------+
|Name   | team |
+-------+------+
|Abel   | a    |
|Bravo  | b    |
|Charle | a    |
|Delta  | a    |
|Echo   | b    |
+-------+------+
```

*Sheet 2*

```
+---------+
|Team a   |
+---------+
|Abel     |
|Charlie  |
|Delta    |
+---------+

+---------+
| Team b  |
+---------+
|Bravo    |
|Echo     |
+---------+
```

I insert the names manually in `Sheet 1`, then locate the team from another spreadsheet using offset. Unfortunately they don't come in order and someone's team a will be 20 people and team b 5 - these values vary but not more than 30 total

Apologies for formatting I'm using my phone, sheet 1 is 2 column, sheet 2 is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for a pivot table and pivot chart.

For this dataset

[image]

and setting this

[image]

you would get the following, where you can filter on team

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea but the wrong way round, the columns on the left are both complete. I need to sort that into two groups on the right

Comment: Now I get what you are asking, please check the edited answer.

Comment: I have done it this way but the error comes when representing the date in graphs. As  this is intended to be 99% automated (only names being entered) then it would generate graphs. 

At present if I take data across, and display scores etc then it shows alot of NA() in the bar charts which I can remove manually but again since this will be used repeatedly and updated about 30times a day is very labour consuming.

Comment: check the edited answer. I think it should fit your needs, now